# Use @Parameterize.Parameters(name ="example)

Tags: java, junit

This is my code:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {

    @Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }
           });
    }

    private int input;
    private int expected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        this.input = input;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(expected, Fibonacci.compute(input));
    }
}
```

In this example  `@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")` refers to first argument in *arraylist* for example, `0, 1,2,3 ...`

Is there any way to include `@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")` directly on method

```
@Test
@Parameterized.Parameters(name = this.input)
public void test() {
    assertEquals(expected, Fibonacci.compute(input));
}
```

I have huge code which does not have static method but add values in the method itself to test, in order to avoid refactoring the whole code how can I make the above work

Comment: You cannot access anything except `compile time constant` in annotation.

Comment: Parameterized can't now, you can try with open source junitparams